# Navigate to first page like Back button in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new in iOS development. I have this Storyboard:

[image]

When I click on Page 1 Bar button item --> go to Page 2 with back button (using push segue)

And basically by click on the back button --> go back to Page 1

As you see I have a Save bar button in Page 2, my question is when I click on this button I want to save my data in database and come back to Page1.

Can you help me how can I go back to first page?

```
- (void)save:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Save");
    // SaveDataToDb
    if(Data successfully saved in database)
         //Go Back to Page 1 ???
    else
         // Proper error message
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]